# ASP.net web api 2 Route-Attribute not working

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, routes

I've the following problem, my route attribute is not working.

I have the following action:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("~api/admin/template/{fileName}")]
public HttpResponseMessage Template(string fileName)
{
    return CreateHtmlResponse(fileName);
}
```

and i want to access the action like `.../api/admin/template/login.html`, so that Template get *login.html* passed as the file name.

But i alsways get: `No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:50121/api/admin/template/login.html'`.

The following request works: `/api/admin/template?fileName=login.html`

Does anyone know, what i am doing wrong with my routing?

**EDIT**:

My route configuration

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                    "API Default", "api/{controller}/{action}",
                    new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

Comment: Did you call `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();`?

Comment: @haim770 yes, that is the solution. If you create an answer, i will accept it, thankl you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to call `MapHttpAttributeRoutes()` so that the Framework will be able to walk through your attributes and register the appropriate routes upon application start:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // you can add manual routes as well
        //config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(...
    }
}
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn479134(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: I'm not following how this class is actually called?

Comment: @leen3o Usually, in your `Global.asax`

Comment: How would you call this in the global.asax? I don't get where HttpConfiguration comes from.

Comment: @leen3o, See http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/configuring-aspnet-web-api

Answer (score 7):

Check your Route attribute's namespace. It should be **System.Web.Http** instead of **System.Web.Mvc**.

Comment: Can't upvote more than once :)
This is usually the solution to this problem, when you create controlles via rightclick->new controller.

Answer (score 6):

```
try adding a forward slash after the tilde
[HttpGet]
[Route("~/api/admin/template/{fileName}")]
public HttpResponseMessage Template(string fileName)
{
    return CreateHtmlResponse(fileName);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Verify that you are using `System.Web.Http.RouteAttribute` and not `System.Web.Mvc.RouteAttribute`

Answer (score 1):

Try this routing in your `WebApiConfig`

```
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

You have to add `RoutePrefix`.

Comment: This routing is for standard MVC controllers, not for API controllers.

Comment: @haim770, That's actually incorrect... MapHttpRoute is for Web Api. MapRoute is for MVC.

Comment: @Slick86, See the initial revision

Comment: Aah, Sorry, missed that

Answer (score 1):

With my Web API 2 project I had to add a `[RoutePrefix("events")]` to the controller for it to pickup the action route attribute.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I added `Route("api/dashboard")` to api controller. 
Changed it to `RoutePrefix("api/dashboard")` . And it works perfectly. 
Also you need `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();` in webapiconfig.cs