# ASP.Net MVC Api Controller - Custom Route

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I know this is a clone of the post [ASP.net web api 2 Route-Attribute not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28067419/asp-net-web-api-2-route-attribute-not-workin), but I am having another issue like this.

I can use the standard api routes if i configure this:

```
  // works just fine
  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
      name: "DefaultApi",
      routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
      defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
  );
  // does absolutley nothing
```

but the `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();` seems to be doing absolutely nothing. No matter what i have tried so far helps.

Has anybody had this issue?

I have tried all the listed routes using the `[Route()]` attribute. Nothing works.

Comment: You should probably take a look at this to see where you went wrong https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: Given that you have not really provided much to go on in terms of details there is way too many possibilities that could be the cause of your problem. You need to review [ask] and then provide a [mcve].

Comment: Also note that `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();` MUST come before convention-based routes.

Comment: Nikosi - Thanks. I did play around with this.

Comment: I actually figured it out - there is an answer on the thread that I linked above by FrenchKevin777 - **Verify that you are using System.Web.Http.RouteAttribute and not System.Web.Mvc.RouteAttribute**

Comment: Glad you figured it eventually. That means however that we can close this question as a duplicate of the linked post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.net web api 2 Route-Attribute not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28067419/asp-net-web-api-2-route-attribute-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I was using the wrong namespace.

`Must use    : System.Web.Http.RouteAttribute 
What I Used : System.Web.Mvc.RouteAttribute`

The answer was posted on the thread which I referenced above - by ed FrenchKevin777